# Who is the U.S. official with the highest position within the U.S. government who has dual citizenship in China and the United States?

Tags: united-states, china, citizenship

Who is the U.S. official with the highest position within the U.S. government who has dual citizenship in China and the United States?

I only know of Conrad Lee, but I don't think he has Chinese citizenship. He was born in China though.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conrad_Lee

> Lee was born in Kunming, China. His father was an aide to warlord Long Yun.[2] After the death of his father, Lee moved to Hong Kong with his mother. In 1958, he moved to the United States to attend college at Seattle Pacific University. He received his bachelor's degree in engineering from the University of Michigan,[3] and an MBA from the University of Washington. He moved to Washington in 1967 to become an engineer for Boeing.[4] He has also worked as a stockbroker.[citation needed]

Comment: I don't think China allows adults to have dual citizenship.

Comment: What is the purpose of this question? Why would it matter if someone had dual citizenship with China? If they wanted to do something wouldn’t they just renounce it to hide that fact?

Comment: Conrad Lee is mayor of Bellevue, WA. I'm not aware of him ever holding a position in the US [Federal] government. Do you mean *any* government position within the US?

Comment: @A.R. China and the US have a treaty with specific provisions applying to US-Chinese dual citizens.

Comment: @A.R.: "I don't think China allows adults to have dual citizenship." Do you have any official source that Chinese citizenship is lost from dual citizenship children when they become adults?

Comment: @user102008 Nope, which is why I didn't make it an answer. That was my understanding from talking to some of my coworkers who moved to the US from China.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## None, China does not recognize dual US citizenship

[According to usa.gov...](https://www.usa.gov/dual-citizenship)

> Your eligibility to become a dual citizen depends on the policies of the second country where you are applying for citizenship...

With a few exceptions for places like Hong Kong, The People's Republic Of China (PRC) does not allow dual citizenship. This is covered by the [Nationality Law of the People's Republic of China](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/residents/immigration/chinese/law.html).

> Article 3:    **The People’s Republic of China does not recognise dual nationality for any Chinese national.**

> Article 5:    Any person born abroad whose parents are both Chinese nationals or one of whose parents is a Chinese national shall have Chinese nationality. **But a person whose parents are both Chinese nationals and have both settled abroad, or one of whose parents is a Chinese national and has settled abroad, and who has acquired foreign nationality at birth shall not have Chinese nationality.**

> Article 9:    **Any Chinese national who has settled abroad and who has been naturalised as a foreign national or has acquired foreign nationality of his own free will shall automatically lose Chinese nationality.**

You can apply to get it back, but you must renounce your former citizenship.

> Article 13:   Foreign nationals who once held Chinese nationality may apply for restoration of Chinese nationality if they have legitimate reasons; **those whose applications for restoration of Chinese nationality have been approved shall not retain foreign nationality.**

The few people who apply to be naturalized PRC citizens must renounce their former nationality.

> Article 8:    Any person who applies for naturalisation as a Chinese national shall acquire Chinese nationality upon approval of his application; **a person whose application for naturalisation as a Chinese national has been approved shall not retain foreign nationality.**

---

By becoming a US citizen Conrad Lee lost his PRC citizenship. And as mayor of a US city he is not a US [Federal] official.

Comment: "The People's Republic Of China (PRC) does not allow dual citizenship": if this is so, why would the PRC sign a treaty with the US that has specific provisions applying to dual Chinese-US citizens?

Comment: "The People's Republic Of China (PRC) does not allow dual citizenship." None of the things you quoted say "does not allow dual citizenship". Article 3 says that the PRC does not "recognize" that Chinese citizens possess dual nationality, meaning that if a person legally possesses Chinese nationality and foreign nationality at the same time, the PRC will only recognize their Chinese nationality (since it says "Chinese citizen") and not recognize their foreign nationality. If there were no dual nationals, then this article would be meaningless since there would be nothing to "not recognize".

Comment: In fact, Articles 4 and 5 provide for children to to be born with dual nationality. A child born in China to one Chinese citizen parent is a Chinese citizen at birth according to Article 4, even if they have foreign nationality at birth from the other parent. A child born outside China to two Chinese citizen parents who have not settled abroad, or to one Chinese citizen parent who has not settled abroad and one foreign national parent, will be a Chinese citizen at birth according to Article 5, even if they have foreign nationality at birth from the other parent or from the country of birth.

Comment: In Article 5, when neither parent is a Chinese citizen who has settled abroad, the part regarding having foreign nationality doesn't apply, since the "and" requires both parts to be satisfied for the child to not have Chinese nationality. [This page](http://zm.china-embassy.gov.cn/chn/fw/hzlxz/202208/t20220827_10756149.htm) from a PRC embassy, items 4, 5, and 11, confirms that a child with foreign nationality is also recognized as a Chinese citizen if the conditions of Article 4 or 5 are met.

Comment: @phoog Which treaty are you referring to?

Comment: @user102008 Points 4 and 5 both say (machine translated) "According to China’s nationality law, your child has Chinese nationality. **In the case of a conflict of nationality, your child should apply for a travel permit according to my relevant regulations.**" which reads to me that if the child has US citizenship that is a conflict. Point 11 is about a child born in China, but there might be ambiguity around whether also have citizenship via their foreign parent? As for article 3, if the PRC does not recognize dual citizenship, neither will the US. Perhaps you should write your own answer.

Comment: I'd like to delete this because I'm not an immigration lawyer and I may have gotten some of the nuisance wrong.

Comment: @Schwern: The child gets a different travel document (which by the way says inside it that the bearer is a citizen of the PRC), but the travel document is not relevant to the question. The question is about citizenship, and the point is, the PRC recognizes the child as a Chinese citizen, while knowing that at the same time the foreign country recognizes the child as having the foreign nationality. Yes, the PRC "does not recognize dual citizenship" in the same way as the US, but you wouldn't say that the US "does not allow dual citizenship", would you?

Comment: @phoog I don't feel confident in this answer and would prefer to delete it. I can't as long as it's accepted. Would you unaccept it, please?

Comment: @user102008 I think I'm over my head here.